# Is there a better way to declare an object

Tags: javascript

Currently I check if sed object already exists as to not wipe it if it does, then create the object.

```
if (typeof result === 'undefined') {
    results = {};
}
```

It's just that I come from using PHP where you don't really have to declare things as much as you do in JS.

Though I tend to use JS objects as I use arrays in PHP, as a way to temporarily store information which I need to access further down in a script.

Comment: Why are you doing that? Is there any good reason they will have previously been set? If not, don't do that.

Comment: better check results or set result...

Comment: @minitech Thats a good question, think I needed for an old project which I had to create an object inside of a loop... Though im not sure why anymore, maybe it would have worked just as well outside the loop. Was under a bit of pressure at the time but not now, hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This wouldn't work if certain values (e.g., `0`, `null`, or `false`) should not be overwritten, but:

```
results = results || {};
```

This works because `||` returns the first value if it is truthy or the second otherwise. `undefined`, along with some other values partially listed above, are falsy, but objects are truthy.

Answer (score 4):

you could do:

```
var results = window.results || {};
```

Answer (score 2):

Just write your code so you never have to guess.  Avoid globals, don't create variables conditionally, set defaults early.  You should only need your pattern in special cases, like writing a library for third parties, using a module system, etc.